# Google App Engine deployment error 502: Bad Gateway with Django and Gunicorn

Tags: django, google-app-engine, deployment, gunicorn, http-status-code-502

I am trying to deploy a Django application on Google App Engine using Gunicorn as the WSGI server. The application works well locally, but when deployed to App Engine, I encounter a 502: Bad Gateway error. I have checked the logs in Google Cloud Console and can't find any relevant errors.

Here is my app.yaml configuration file:

```html
runtime: python311

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT --timeout 120 LyAnt.wsgi:application

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "LyAnt.settings"
  ENV: "PRODUCTION"

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: auto

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 2
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic
```

I tried running Gunicorn locally, but it does not work due to the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'" error. I understand that Gunicorn is not recommended for Windows environments, so I tested my application locally using Waitress, and it works fine.

I expected my application to work on Google App Engine after deployment, but I am encountering a 502 error instead.

Comment: You should actually include the log output for the 502 error in your question. Someone might see something in it that you didn't. Another option is to actually run your app with ```dev_appserver.py``` on your local environment. This is the closest simulation of Production. Since you're on Windows, you can use this [patch](https://github.com/NoCommandLine/dev_appserver-python3-windows) from us to do so since by default, ```dev_appserver.py``` isn't supported for Python 3 on Windows.